# Interpret bell curve, calculate 95th percentile value

Tags: data-transformation, standard-deviation

I have data showing the distribution of a given metric across a population.

The data is broken up into increments, with values for the 90th 97.5th and 99th percentiles.

How can I interpret this data to predict what the 95th percentile would be?

| Percentile | 1 | 2.5 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 | 90 | 97.5 | 99 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | 5.8 | 7.1 | 9.5 | 11 | 12.1 | 13.1 | 14 | 15.6 | 17.4 | 19.5 | 22.3 | 26.7 | 29.1 |

Comment: If you $q=\Phi^{-1}(p/100)$ vs $v$ ... you'll notice that the relationship looks suspiciously close to a linear spline.

Comment: The question title says "bell curve", but the question itself just says "distribution".  Are you supposed to assume that the distribution is normal / Gaussian ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

**1. Linear interpolation** (simple, but with a larger error): Interpolate between the 90th and 97.5th percentile. Your $x$ should be between 22.3 and 26.7, two-thirds towards the latter.

**2. Curve fitting** (computationally more complex, but more precise): You have $x$-values: 5.8, 7.1, ..., 29.1, and the corresponding $y$-values, which you should divide by 100 to get the probabilities: 0.01, 0.025, ..., 0.99. You adjust the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ parameters of the normal CDF, $\Phi(x; \mu, \sigma)$, to achieve the best fit between the given $y$-values and the ones given by $\Phi$. Finally, you calculate the inverse, $\Phi^{-1}(0.95; \mu, \sigma)$ to predict the 95th percentile.

Something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.stats import norm as gauss

# the data, as given in the question:
y = np.array([1, 2.5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 97.5, 99]) / 100
x = np.array([5.8, 7.1, 9.5, 11, 12.1, 13.1, 14, 15.6, 17.4, 19.5, 22.3, 26.7, 29.1])

# fit the Gaussian CDF to the data:
res = opt.minimize(
  lambda params: np.sum((gauss.cdf(x, loc=params[0], scale=params[1]) - y)**2),
  [10, 10]
)
# calculate the 95th percentile:
x_95 = gauss.ppf(.95, res.x[0], res.x[1])


#### the rest is just for visualisation:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = np.linspace(5, 30, 100)
plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.plot(xx, gauss.cdf(xx, res.x[0], res.x[1]))
plt.plot([min(xx), x_95], [.95, .95], ':', c='k')
plt.plot([x_95, x_95], [0, .95], ':', c='k', label='$x_{95} = $' + f'{x_95:.2f}')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.title(f'$\mu$ = {res.x[0]:.2f}, $\sigma$ = {res.x[1]:.2f}')
```

[image: Gaussian CDF fitted to data]

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer

Comment: The problem with fitting the cumulative normal curve is that it doesn't fit the observed data very well in the region of interest, near *y* = 0.95.  The curve is above all the points in this region.  If a better curve couldn't be found, it would be better to just interpolate linearly between *y* = 0.90 and *y* = 0.975.  As you mention, the answer should be closer to 26.  With this method I get c. 25.2.  (`slope=(97.5-90)/(26.7-22.3); intercept=90-slope*22.3; (95-intercept)/slope`.   In my answer below, fitting just half of the data, I get an answer of 24.4, but this fit isn't perfect either.

Answer (score 2):

My supposition is that the question expects you to assume that the distribution is a normal distribution. From there, you could assume that the mean of the distribution is estimated by the median (50th percentile), which in this case is 14.  And then the difference between the 50th percentile and 97.5th percentile is twice the estimate for the standard deviation (according to the 68–95–99.7 rule ( [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) ).

What's curious, though, is that the difference between the 50th and 97.5th percentiles suggests an *sd* of 6.35 ((26.7 - 14) / 2).  Whereas the difference between the 50th and 2.5th percentiles suggests an *sd* of 3.45 ((14 - 7.1) / 2).

We could also estimate the *sd* from the the difference between the 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles (4.90, (26.7 - 7.1) / 4 ).

The upshot for me looking at the given data is that the percentiles <= 50 can be fit well with one normal distribution, and that the percentiles >= 50 can be fit well with a different normal distribution.

In the attached plots, the blue line uses *mean* = 14, *sd* = 6.35, and the light blue line uses *mean* = 14, *sd* = 3.45.  The gray line splits the difference and uses *mean* = 14, *sd* = 4.90.

Using the blue line would probably be the best way to estimate the 95th percentile.  Unless a better model could be found to estimate the whole distribution.

The R code I used follows.

[image]

[image]

```r
Percentile = c(1, 2.5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 97.5, 
             99)/100
Value   = c(5.8, 7.1, 9.5, 11, 12.1, 13.1, 14, 15.6, 17.4, 19.5, 
            22.3, 26.7, 29.1)

P   = 0:10000 / 10000
M   = 14
SD  = (26.7 - 14)   / 2
SD2 = (14   -  7.1) / 2
SD3 = (26.7 -  7.1) / 4

plot(Percentile ~ Value, ylim=c(0,1.1), xlim=c(0, 35))

lines(qnorm(P, M, SD), P, col="blue", lwd=2)

lines(qnorm(P, M, SD2), P, col="cornflowerblue", lwd=2)

plot(Percentile ~ Value, ylim=c(0,1.1), xlim=c(0, 35))

lines(qnorm(P, M, SD3), P, col="darkgray", lwd=2)

Answer = qnorm(0.95, M, SD)

Answer
```

Comment: If the objective *solely* is to interpolate the 95th percentile, this approach can fail (dramatically) unless the bottom 90% of the data are very close to Normal!  A simpler, general, and more accurate method is interpolation (linear or quadratic) within the Normal probability plot of the data.

Comment: I agree, @whuber .  I'm assuming the question is a "self-study" question.  In that case, I  assume the question expects the answerer to assume that the distribution is normal, and use the given information to estimate the mean and standard deviation.  But the actual distribution is somewhat odd if this is the intention.  ...  But I could be totally wrong.  Maybe it's real, empirical data.

Comment: Sometimes distributions are summarized in this fashion.  It's always good to ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the answer. This is not a homework question, it's for my own interest interpreting data from a scientific study. I don't know much about statistics. 

My understanding is now is that it's not correct to assume the data would follow a bell curve distribution, and in fact you were able to find two separate functions which together closely match the data, giving an estimate of 24.44.

Comment: @Edward , this is actual data, not generated from some kind of model ?  It seems suspiciously close to a hypothetical curve.  ...  In any case, fitting the whole distribution to a cumulative normal curve isn't the best fit.  Perhaps a better sigmoid curve could be found. Or fitting a curve to just a few points near *y* = 0.95 would give a more precise estimate.  Or, actually, just interpolating with a linear function between two points gives a decent estimate.